# How to reduce the run - time of python program ( program takes a lot of time in execution)

Tags: python

I am solving The Minion Game problem on hackerank and i failed the testcases in which the run time of code was too much .
The code is:

```
def minion_game(word):
    # initialize the scores of player 1 and 2 to 0
    # initialize the jump for index
    # initialize a string of vowels
    scoreOfStuart, scoreOfKevin, adder, vowels = 0, 0, 1, "AEIOU"

    i = 0
    while i < len(word):
        # initialize a list to store all the possible substrings for each length of substrings
        listOfSubStrings = []
        listOfSubStrings = [word[j : j + adder] for j in range(len(word) - i)]
        # end nested for loop ---- now a list of all possible substrings is present
        # another nested for loop to determine the score
        listOfStuart = [j for j in listOfSubStrings if j[0] not in vowels]
        listOfKevin = [j for j in listOfSubStrings if j[0] in vowels]
        scoreOfStuart += len(listOfStuart)
        scoreOfKevin += len(listOfKevin)

        # increment in adder by 1
        adder += 1
        i += 1
    # printing the scores
    if scoreOfStuart > scoreOfKevin:
        print("Stuart", scoreOfStuart)
    elif scoreOfStuart < scoreOfKevin:
        print("Kevin", scoreOfKevin)
    else:
        print("Draw")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    string = input().upper()
    minion_game(string)
```

I have tried list comprehension instead of a for loop for appending strings into lists and simple while loop instead of main for loop, still the run time has not become less.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Without thinking of a more clever algorithm, for one, `vowels` should probably be a set if you're only doing `in` lookups. Secondly, perhaps the stuart and kevin loops should be a single loop, since they're doing practically the same work twice?

Comment: Anyway, working code that needs review or optimization belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It looks like you're only building listOfStuart and listOfKevin to then sum their elements, could you maybe directly calculate the sum instead of going through a list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the substrings at all, except for checking the first letter, so you can get rid of calculating them alltogether:

```
def minion_game(word):
    scoreOfStuart, scoreOfKevin, vowels = 0, 0, set("AEIOU")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        for j in range(len(word)-i)):
            if word[j] in vowels:
                scoreOfKevin += 1
            else:
                scoreOfStuart += 1

    # printing the scores
    if scoreOfStuart > scoreOfKevin:
        print("Stuart", scoreOfStuart)
    elif scoreOfStuart < scoreOfKevin:
        print("Kevin", scoreOfKevin)
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

Besides, you can notice that you don't need to do the nested loop as well, you can just iterate the word once, because there are `len(word)-i` strings that start with the same letter. E.g. word `banana`, and `i==1`, there are substrings `a`, `an`, `ana`, `anan`, `anana` a total of `len(word)-i == 6 - 1 == 5`, thus you can add this score to Kevin directrly

```
def minion_game(word):
    scoreOfStuart, scoreOfKevin, vowels = 0, 0, set("AEIOU")
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] in vowels:
            scoreOfKevin += len(word)-i
        else:
            scoreOfStuart += len(word)-i

    # printing the scores
    if scoreOfStuart > scoreOfKevin:
        print("Stuart", scoreOfStuart)
    elif scoreOfStuart < scoreOfKevin:
        print("Kevin", scoreOfKevin)
    else:
        print("Draw")
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the guidance. I have been solving problems in python for 4 months now and am currently learning OOPs in java. I have solved quite a number of problems but am unable to think of an efficient logic. How to overcome this?

Comment: @ZainabSaad It's not something you can willingly overcome. It comes with practice. Having a higher education in computer science or math also helps

Comment: does getting code reviewed helps?

Comment: @ZainabSaad I don't think so, but trying to solve problems harder than you currently can, and then analyzing solutions of other people helped me once\

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not using the for lop or list comprehension or a while loop. All of these methods depend on the length of the word. Let us say n.
So in all of your algorithms the time complexity in o(n).
Hackerrank expects you to solve this problem in a time less than o(n).

Learn more about time complexities [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-time-complexity-simple-examples/)

Comment: OP code's complexity is worse than quadratic. A O(n) solution like the second one by Alexey is ok

Answer (score 0):

In any problem in competitive programming, some estimates on the time complexity of your algorithm can be made, based on the constraints on the input:

```
| Constraint      | Required Time Complexity                   |
|-----------------|--------------------------------------------|
| n <= 10         | O(n!)                                      |
| n <= 20         | O(2n)                                      |
| n <= 500        | O(n3)                                      |
| n <= 5000       | O(n2)                                      |
| n <= 10^6       | O(n) or O(n log n)                         |
| n can be > 10^6 | O(1) or O(log n) (and in some cases O(√n)) |
```

This Should give you the intuition of which way to go.

Here you are generating all the substrings and filtering based on the first letter. Do we actually need the substrings or just the count. From the question https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-minion-game/problem its okay to have duplicates (ANA occurs twice in BANANA. Hence, Kevin will get 2 Points).

Solution : considering the first letter of a string, you can look at how many combinations of substrings start with the letter you are iterating over and add that number to kevin or stuart instead of adding one at a time. If you need the code. The best best place will be the discussion section of the problem.